# Удаление элемента из DOM

Tags: javascript

Есть попап который заключен в тег `<script>` как темплейт,по клика на кнопку открыть я буду c помощью библиотеки `jsrender` рендерить данный теймлейт,а так же по кнопке закрыть буду удалять его из `DOM`, чтобы при каждый клике инициализировался новые попап.Вопрос состоит в том,дорогая ли операция каждый раз удалять его из дом модели? Или просто сделать попап и изначально присвоить ему `display none`, при клике естественно показывать его и далее при закрытии закрывать и отщичать все значения инпутов,то есть при этом не надо каждый раз инициализировать новый попап.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, лучше просто скрывать. Но при условии, что функционально блок не важен. То есть не стоит забывать, что спрятанный блок, все же присутствует на странице, и данные с него могут быть получены.

Comment: Спасибо так и сделаю